# Linux more, how to move to beginning of file?

Tags: linux, more

How to show the beginning of file or show the exact line with move terminal command if I gone to the next page?

Comment: Already read the man page to that command?

Comment: Yes. And read help while using more command, nothing was helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `less` you can press `g` to jump to the beginning of the file or `G` to jump to the end of the file.

If you're stuck with `more` you can cheat the "skip backward k screenfuls" command by providing a large argument: press `9999b`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually stuck with more command because of it's a homework and I was told to use this command.

Comment: With `less` running, you can also press `h` to see the Help Menu. In the "JUMPING" section it shows the `g` and `G` commands. After 10 years of using less, I've finally learned how to go back to the beginning of the file, and that there is a built-in help menu!